# sls remove without .serverless directory

Tags: serverless-framework, aws-serverless

The Serverless Framewokrk creates the `.serverless` directory with configuration of AWS components.

If it is not present what will happen with `sls remove`?

Imagine that someone else deployed, and I just cloned the repo and need to remove everything. Should I add this directory in the repository?

Answer (score 0):

`sls remove` will be referring to serverless.yml file and will be removing the stack.

`.serverless` directory is created when you do a `sls deploy`

It will basically have some contents like zip file which is used to deploy it to AWS.
So you need not create an `.serverless` directory manually for anything. It is also not recommended to push this directory to git either.